# Testing / Fixtures: setup Entries in Structure

Tags: tests

**Background**: I have experience with vanilla PHPUnit testing of projects, but this the first attempt at both testing a Craft project and using Codeception for testing.

**Case**: I have a section of type structure of maximum 2 levels deep. The URL I want to test, i.e. `/some-section/some-entry` shows content of both the parent and children, which is aggregated through some business logic.

**Problem**: I am having trouble setting this up in fixture files. I created a fixture class the extends the `EntryFixture` class. But I have not figured out how to create a data file that creates the parent-child relation.

When I go through the code, that relationship would normally be made through setting the `newParentId`. But no ID exists. I have not figured out a way to define this in the data file. For now I am going to use two fixture classes, one for the parent entries, and one for the child entries. In the fixture class for the child entries I then overrule the `getData`-method so that I can resolve the actual parentId by querying the database for the previously loaded fixture records.

However this does not seem the cleanest way and I wonder if I am missing the obvious solution here?